# First pin problem

Tags: microcontroller, gps, gprs

Is this pin first pin of Quectel L76 ?
[image]

[image]

Im confused with this :

[image]

Comment: It appears as though pin 1 is lower right if you are looking at the device top down; the triangle marking (pin 1) therefore appears at top right if you flip it over and look at the other side.

Comment: @vir sorry .. i dont understand your point

Comment: I think that you are confused between bottom-view and top-view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the ground plane on the underside of the module.  It connects to pins 1, 10, and 12 - Ground.

[image]

The "L76 Series (Top View)" image in the question, for some reason, is rotated 180°.

This is fairly common... I think to keep us sharp.